# How to recursively type a mirroring function

Tags: flowtype

Say we've got a function, `keyMirror` that takes an Object with arbitrary values and returns another object with values that match the keys. For example:

Input:

```
{
  KEY_ONE: '',
  KEY_TWO: '',
}
```

Output:

```
{
  KEY_ONE: 'KEY_ONE',
  KEY_TWO: 'KEY_TWO',
}
```

Using `$ObjMapi`, typing this would be fairly trivial:

```
type keyMirror<O: {}> = (obj: O) => $ObjMapi<O, <K>(k: K) => K>;
```

My question is: How would we type a recursive `keyMirror` function? For example, given the input:

```
{
  GROUP_ONE: {
    KEY_ONE: '',
  },
  GROUP_TWO: {
    KEY_TWO: '',
  },
}
```

and output:

```
{
  GROUP_ONE: {
    KEY_ONE: 'GROUP_ONE.KEY_ONE',
  },
  GROUP_TWO: {
    KEY_TWO: 'GROUP_TWO.KEY_TWO',
  },
}
```